# Creating stored procedure to insert new rows into a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a stored procedure which fulfill the following question,

Write a stored procedure called event_registration which handles the participant's entry for an event. When a participant registers for an event, they may also choose to create or join a group.

Your procedure must take four input parameters:

- participant number
- exhibition date
- event type description
- group name.

The procedure must:

- check if the input exhibition date and event name are valid
- check if the participants wants to create/join a group (ie. they provide a group name) and, if provided, whether the group name exists for the input exhibition:

  - If the group does not exist then the procedure should add a new group and assign this participant as the group leader, or
  - If the group exists then the procedure should add the participant into the existing group

So the below are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE group 
(
    group_id         NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    group_name       VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    exhibition_date  DATE NOT NULL,
    group_no_members NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    event_id         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    entry_no         NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    char_id          NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE TABLE event 
(
    event_id         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    exhibition_date  DATE NOT NULL,
    eventtype_code   CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    event_starttime  DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE eventtype 
(
    eventtype_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    eventtype_desc VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE exhibition 
(
    exhibition_date     DATE NOT NULL,
    exhibition_name     VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    exhibition_director VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    exhibition_location VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE entry 
(
    event_id         NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    entry_no         NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    entry_starttime  DATE,
    entry_finishtime DATE,
    part_no          NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    group_id         NUMBER(3),
    char_id          NUMBER(3)
);
```

And this is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE event_registration 
    (new_part_no IN NUMBER, 
     new_exhibition_date IN DATE, 
     new_eventtype_desc IN VARCHAR2, 
     new_group_name IN VARCHAR2, 
     output OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS
    exhibition_date_and_event_found NUMBER; group_found NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO exhibition_date_and_event_found 
    FROM event 
    NATURAL JOIN eventtype 
    WHERE exhibition_date = new_exhibition_date 
      AND eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc;
IF (exhibition_date_and_event_found = 0) THEN 
output := 'Invalid exhibition date/This exhibition does not have this event type';
ELSE
    IF(new_group_name != NULL) THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO group_found FROM group NATURAL JOIN exhibition WHERE group_name = new_group_name AND exhibition_date = new_exhibition_date;
        IF(group_found = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO group VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM group), new_group_name, TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 1, (SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')), (SELECT MAX(entry_no)+1 FROM entry WHERE event_id = (SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))), NULL);
        INSERT INTO entry VALUES ((SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')), (SELECT MAX(entry_no)+1 FROM entry WHERE event_id = (SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))), NULL, NULL, new_part_no, (SELECT group_id FROM group WHERE group_name = new_group_name), NULL);
        ELSE --group already exist 
        --update the group member number by 1 
        UPDATE group
        SET group_no_members = group_no_members + 1
        WHERE group_name = new_group_name;
        INSERT INTO entry VALUES ((SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')), (SELECT MAX(entry_no)+1 FROM entry WHERE event_id = (SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))), NULL, NULL, new_part_no, (SELECT group_id FROM group WHERE group_name = new_group_name), NULL);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO entry VALUES ((SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')), (SELECT MAX(entry_no)+1 FROM entry WHERE event_id = (SELECT event_id FROM event NATURAL JOIN eventtype WHERE eventtype_desc = new_eventtype_desc AND exhibition_date = TO_DATE(new_exhibition_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))), NULL, NULL, new_part_no, NULL, NULL);
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

The procedure is not done yet but I think it is good enough to be compiled, but when I run it, it gives out errors like

```
Procedure EVENT_REGISTRATION compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
12/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/21     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
18/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
18/21     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
21/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
21/21     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
Errors: check compiler log
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your procedure does not generate that error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ffb2a0ba5e3d3f9dba1cd20ced12c77a)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use constraints on your tables (primary keys, foreign keys, etc.).
2. Use sequences for primary key values (**NEVER** use `SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ...` to generate ids as you are likely to get duplicates on a parallel system).
3. If you use constraints then you don't need to check that the exhibition date and event (exhibition?) name are correct as, if they are not, the constraint will raise an exception when you try to against a non-existent relationship.
4. **NEVER** use `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (...)`, you should always explicitly name the columns you are inserting into using:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
   ```
5. Do not keep using the same query over-and-over to find the `event_id`. Find it once and store it in a PL/SQL variable and then use the PL/SQL variable the next time.
6. `GROUP` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612); do not use it as an identifier.
7. You cannot compare a value to `NULL` using `value != NULL` as `NULL` is never equal or not-equal to anything else; you need to use `value IS NOT NULL`.
8. Make sure you do not have cyclic referential constraints in your tables (i.e. `GROUP` has an `entry_no` which refers to the `entry` table and the `entry` table has a `group_id` column that refers to the `GROUP` table. You do not need both and when you put constraints in then you will get a cycle.)

---

Something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE exhibition 
(
    exhibition_date     DATE
                        PRIMARY KEY
                        NOT NULL,
    exhibition_name     VARCHAR2(50)
                        NOT NULL,
    exhibition_director VARCHAR2(50)
                        NOT NULL,
    exhibition_location VARCHAR2(50)
                        NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE eventtype 
(
    eventtype_code CHAR(3)
                   PRIMARY KEY
                   NOT NULL,
    eventtype_desc VARCHAR2(50)
                   NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE event 
(
    event_id         NUMBER(6)
                     NOT NULL
                     PRIMARY KEY,
    exhibition_date  REFERENCES exhibition(exhibition_date)
                     NOT NULL,
    eventtype_code   REFERENCES eventtype(eventtype_code)
                     NOT NULL,
    event_starttime  DATE
                     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "GROUP"
(
    group_id         NUMBER(3)
                     NOT NULL
                     PRIMARY KEY,
    group_name       VARCHAR2(30)
                     UNIQUE
                     NOT NULL,
    group_no_members NUMBER(2)
                     NOT NULL,
    event_id         REFERENCES event(event_id)
                     NOT NULL,
    char_id          NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE TABLE entry 
(
    event_id         REFERENCES event(event_id)
                     NOT NULL,
    entry_no         NUMBER(5)
                     PRIMARY KEY
                     NOT NULL,
    entry_starttime  DATE,
    entry_finishtime DATE,
    part_no          NUMBER(5)
                     NOT NULL,
    group_id         NUMBER(3)
                     REFERENCES "GROUP"(group_id),
    char_id          NUMBER(3)
);
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE group_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE entry_seq;
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE event_registration 
    (new_part_no IN NUMBER, 
     new_exhibition_date IN DATE, 
     new_eventtype_desc IN VARCHAR2, 
     new_group_name IN VARCHAR2, 
     output OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS
  v_event_id EVENT.EVENT_ID%TYPE;
  v_group_id "GROUP".GROUP_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT e.event_id
  INTO   v_event_id
  FROM   event e
         INNER JOIN eventtype et
         ON (e.eventtype_code = et.eventtype_code)
  WHERE  exhibition_date = new_exhibition_date
  AND    eventtype_desc  = new_eventtype_desc;

  IF new_group_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    MERGE INTO "GROUP" g
    USING DUAL
    ON (g.group_name = new_group_name)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET group_no_members = group_no_members + 1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (
        group_id,
        group_name,
        group_no_members,
        event_id,
        char_id
      ) VALUES (
        GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
        new_group_name,
        1,
        v_event_id,
        NULL
      );
      
    SELECT group_id
    INTO   v_group_id
    FROM   "GROUP"
    WHERE  group_name = new_group_name;
  END IF;
        
  INSERT INTO entry (
    event_id,
    entry_no,
    entry_starttime,
    entry_finishtime,
    part_no,
    group_id,
    char_id
  )VALUES (
    v_event_id,
    entry_seq.NEXTVAL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    new_part_no,
    v_group_id,
    NULL
  );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    output := 'Invalid exhibition date/This exhibition does not have this event type';
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d24e6cbbd16a0204c58301b90122a2c9)*